# Затемнение изображения перед вставкой в ImageView

Tags: android, android-sdk, изображения, imageview

Я получаю картинки от сервера, но перед тем как вставить их в ImageView Мне их необходимо "затемнить". Как это сделать? Средствами андроид или может кодом?

Comment: Положите сверху вьюху с полупрозрачным чёрным фоном

Answer (score 3):

Просто засуньте `ImageView` во `FrameLayout`. И выставьте `FrameLayout`:

```
android:foreground="#99000000"
```

Answer (score 1):

Из разметки можно затемнить методом android:tint.
Пример:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:tint="#80000000"/>
```

Comment: тинт поддерживается только с API 21. к тому же он или заменит картинку или она его закроет

Comment: Если активити наследуется от AppCompatActivity, то всё будет отлично работать и на устройствах < API 21

Comment: а вы проверьте) вы указали неймспейс `android`. тут `appcompat` не поможет

Comment: Поможет! ImageView будет автоматически конвертирован в AppCompatImageView. А в AppCompatImageView есть поддержка "android:tint".

Answer (score 1):

По колхозному можно поверх этого ImageView навесить такой же по размеру ImageView с нужным background тёмного фона и альфой нужного значения и хоть анимировать, хоть просто setVisiblity(VISIBLE/INVISIBLE), но это костыль конечно. Наверняка есть более цивилизованный и изящный способ.

Answer (score 1):

можно попробовать через Picasso transform.
или использовать [готовую библиотеку](https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations)
 (опять же для Picasso)